# Puppeteer Function to PuppeteerSharp

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am new to puppeteersharp and puppeteer in general.
I am trying to convert a function that is used in puppeteer to puppeteerSharp and i am wondering how to do it.
Here is the puppeteer function(this one scroll down to the end of the page):

```
async function autoScroll(page){
await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var totalHeight = 0;
        var distance = 100;
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
            var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
            window.scrollBy(0, distance);
            totalHeight += distance;

            if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                clearInterval(timer);
                resolve();
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Anyone Can please tell me how can i manage to get this to work with puppeteerSharp?
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `EvaluateFunctionAsync` and pass that function as `string`.

```
await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync(@"async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var totalHeight = 0;
        var distance = 100;
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
            var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
            window.scrollBy(0, distance);
            totalHeight += distance;

            if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                clearInterval(timer);
                resolve();
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}");
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer it worked for me. I should have guessed it.

Comment: Also i wana ask you if there is an equivalence for `await page.addStyleTag({
    content: '@page { size: auto; }',
})`

Comment: @HarimandaJerrysRandriamire yes there is :) https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_AddStyleTagAsync_PuppeteerSharp_AddTagOptions_

Comment: I have used `await page.AddStyleTagAsync(new AddTagOptions { Content= "@page { size: auto; }" });` but the @page isn't injected to the <style> tag of the page